# non-blocking require in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is there a way to use `require` (or something else which is equivalent) on a server, at runtime (serve-time), without blocking the whole thing?

I'm trying to add functions defined by the user, after which he can use them in a language I'm implementing.

So, for example:

**toaprse.mylanguage**

```
#bind somefunctions.js
x = somefunctions.func1();
```

I could do a simple require('somefunction'); but I don't want to block node, which I understand is the case.

I just want to pass functions to my framework, it doesn't have to be `require` but it seems natural.

Comment: The correct practice is to have all requires run on the server's initialization. If you're using many custom libraries you wish to lazy load, you might be able to achieve that with requirejs http://requirejs.org/docs/node.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how require is implemented:

```
> console.log(require.extensions['.js'].toString())
function (module, filename) {
  var content = NativeModule.require('fs').readFileSync(filename, 'utf8');
  module._compile(stripBOM(content), filename);
}
```

You can do the same thing in your app. I guess something like this would work:

```
var fs = require('fs')

require.async = function(filename, callback) {
  fs.readFile(filename, 'utf8', function(err, content) {
    if (err) return callback(err)
    module._compile(content, filename)

    // this require call won't block anything because of caching
    callback(null, require(filename))
  })
}

require.async('./test.js', function(err, module) {
  console.log(module)
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Promises](http://www.promisejs.org/intro/) pattern. Using Promises, you can delegate execution of an asynchronous operation to a method which will call you back in case of errors or after successful execution of given operation.

Here is some node modules implementing this patterns:

- npm install [promise](https://npmjs.org/package/promise)
- npm install [q](https://npmjs.org/package/q)
- npm install [when](https://npmjs.org/package/when)
- npm install [rsvp](https://npmjs.org/package/rsvp)
- npm install [vow](https://npmjs.org/package/vow)

It works, I Promise ;)