# Should I avoid calling require when responding to a request?

Tags: node.js

Is `require`ing a module going to block every single request? According to the [docs](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_caching), the module is cached after the first `require` but I wanted to see if it's an anti-pattern to do a dynamic `require` when responding to a request.

Comment: it's slow and redundant. But that's fine...if you want a really laggy, slow web service :)

Comment: @Markasoftware: Wrong.  `require()` caches modules, so duplicate `require()`s are fast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, it won't block on every request (as long as you're requiring the same module each time), and it's not an anti-pattern.

If you're loading the same module on each request, any call to `require` will return instantly (because the module will have already been loaded, compiled, and cached). If, however, many different modules may be required so that you don't get the benefit of caching, it may be better to do an asynchronous require.

But something like this?

```
function handler(req, res) { require('fs').readFile(…); }
```

No big deal. It's just a matter of style.

Answer (score 1):

I am often told that blocking of any kind is a no-no in node.js, and that asynchronicity is one of its main imperatives. You could try the following.

Quoting the answer from [non-blocking require in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21670317/non-blocking-require-in-node-js)

---

This is how require is implemented:

```
> console.log(require.extensions['.js'].toString())
function (module, filename) {
     var content = NativeModule.require('fs').readFileSync(filename, 'utf8');
     module._compile(stripBOM(content), filename);
}
```

You can do the same thing in your app. I guess something like this would work:

```
var fs = require('fs')

require.async = function(filename, callback) {
  fs.readFile(filename, 'utf8', function(err, content) {
    if (err) return callback(err)
    module._compile(content, filename)

    // this require call won't block anything because of caching
    callback(null, require(filename))
  })
}

require.async('./test.js', function(err, module) {
  console.log(module)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not about slow or fast. require is synchronous operation. This means that it will block whole server while executing. If you have 100000 connections all will wait for 100000 requires.

Never use require inside loop, it is bad practice.

So answer to your original question is YES.